# Copying filtered data to a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to filter data out by criteria in column D and copy the filter data in column C to a different sheet. This code works when I run this code while I am in the data sheet but it won't run and gives me Run-time error '1004'
Selection method of Range class failed, highlighting the first line of the code.
Can anyone help me so that I can run this code in any worksheet?

```
Sheets("Data").Range("D1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$AI").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:= _
    "Production"
Range(ActiveSheet.Range("C2"), ActiveSheet.Range("C2").End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Excluding List").Select
Range("B3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("Data").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Sheets("Data").Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = False
ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
```

Comment: does changing Sheets("Data").Range("D1").Select to Sheets("Data").Select make any difference?

Comment: No it doesn't. I have
For Each slcr In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
        slcr.ClearManualFilter
    Next slcr
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Excluding")
       .SlicerItems("Y").Selected = False
       .SlicerItems("N").Selected = True
    End With

Could this possibly cause error? this is what I have right before that code

Comment: I removed that line and checked but still no good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Data.Activate` at the top of your code

Comment: It works now, thanks so much. May I ask why you need that?